# (Macbook Pro 2020, M1) How do we stop the white flashes on safari dark mode?

Tags: macos, safari, bug

I've included a gif below of the issue. Every time I open a new tab in safari, I get a momentary white flash. I've tried almost everything, from using half a dozen dark mode extensions (dark reader, noir, nitefall, etc.) To injecting code into safari with user scripts, to modifying the CSS, to trying to use apple scripts to set a page delay. If anyone has a solution, I'd be incredibly grateful!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution found: Have both nitefall, and darkreader installed at the same time.

EDIT: Real solution - don't use safari. Pasted details from comment below:

> Try using a browser that isn't safari. I recommend edge, arc, or chrome. In arc or chrome, go to chrome://flags and in edge go to edge://flags and in either turn on "auto dark mode for web contents". It's also good to have a dark mode extension like dark reader installed to complement this, otherwise stuff gets messed up. This will force dark mode everywhere on everything, so you shouldn't use it in any browser you use for any kind of website or app GUI debugging because your CSS styles will not properly display. BTW safari keeps getting hit with unpatched zero days...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me on macOS Sonoma (14.1)

Comment: @intagli Try using a browser that isn't safari. I recommend edge, arc, or chrome. In arc or chrome, go to `chrome://flags` and in edge go to `edge://flags` and in either turn on "auto dark mode for web contents". It's also good to have a dark mode extension like dark reader installed to complement this, otherwise stuff gets messed up. This will force dark mode everywhere on everything, so you shouldn't use it in any browser you use for any kind of website or app GUI debugging because your CSS styles will not properly display. BTW safari keeps getting hit with unpatched zero days...